# My code is returning a http 415 response when twilio receives an sms message

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, twilio

I've configured a webhook in Twilio to point to the below controller when someone sends an sms to my Twilio phone number.  But, when an sms is sent, Twilio pops up a 11200 error and ngrok is telling me I'm returning an HTTP 415 error.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Here is the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(SmsRequest incomingMessage)
    {
        var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();
        messagingResponse.Message(_incomingSMSService.parseIncomingMessage(incomingMessage.From, incomingMessage.Body));

        return TwiML(messagingResponse);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The SmsRequest is coming from the form data, so the controller should have [FormData]SmsRequest incomingMessage in it like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FormData]SmsRequest incomingMessage)
    {
        var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();
        messagingResponse.Message(_incomingSMSService.parseIncomingMessage(incomingMessage.From, incomingMessage.Body));

        return TwiML(messagingResponse);
    }
```